# Understanding the notations of the expectation of a random variable

Tags: probability, notation, expected-value

We know that if $P$ is a probability in the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$, then we can define a distribuition function $F$ as following:
$$F(x):= P((-\infty,x])), \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
By the Carathéodory's extension theorem we can prove that the converse is also valid, that is:
if $F$ is a distibuition function, then there is a unique $P_{\small{F}}$ in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ that
$$F(x)= P_{\small{F}}((-\infty,x])),\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
In other words, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the set of probabilities in  $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ and the set of all distribuition functions.

$Remake:$:: If $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mu) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable, we can define a probability in  $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ and a distribuition function, respectively, as following:
$$P_{\small{X}}(B) := \mu(X \in B),\quad B \in \mathcal{B}$$
$$F_{\small{X}}(x) := P_{\small{X}}((-\infty, x]))= \mu(X \leq x), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}$$

A random variable is continue (absolutly?) if there is a density (non negative) function $f$ such that
$$F_{\small{X}}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(y)dy$$
I dont will write the Lebesgue integral definition, but it is supossed that the classical definition is well known. I would like to remember its notations
$$E(X) = \int_{\Omega}Xd\mu = \int_{\Omega}X^{+}d\mu - \int_{\Omega}X^{-}d\mu$$
Although I consider the one-to-one correspondence between $F_{X}$ and $P_X$, I can not find, besides the notations justificatives, good arguments for the following equivalences (for each iquality)

$$\int_{\Omega}Xd\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}} xdF_{\small{X}}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} xdP_{\small{X}}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x f(x)dx$$
Some justificatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider measurable spaces $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{A}_2)$ and a measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{A_1})$. Any measurable function $X:\Omega_1\to \Omega_2$ induces a measure $\mu_X$ on $\Omega_2$ through $\mu_X(A_2)=\mu( X^{-1}(A_2))$ for $A_2 \in \mathcal{A}_2$, the pushforward measure. If $g:\Omega_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function, then $\int_{\Omega_2} g ~\mathrm{d}(\mu_X) = \int_{\Omega_1} g \circ X ~\mathrm{d}\mu$. Take for $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{A}_2)$ the real numbers with the borel sigma algebra and for $g$ the identity. Then you have

$$\int_{\Omega_1}X~\mathrm{d}\mu = \int_ {\Omega_1} id(X) \mathrm{d}\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}} id ~\mathrm{d}\mu_X.$$

This gives you the  equivalence between the first and the third expression in your last serie of equations: you can calculate the expectation through integration with respect to the pushforward measure. The second and third expression just differ by notation: $dF_X$, stresses that this is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral. The last expression is a property of absolutely continuous measures: if $\mu=f dx$ is a absolutely continuous measure with density $f$, then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g \cdot f d\lambda$, for all integrable $g$, where $\lambda$ is the onedimensional Lebesgue measure.

Comment: The equivalence between the first and the third expression is ok. Now, about the justification $(\mu = fdx)$ of the last expression: can I afirm that it is consequence of the  radon nikodym theorem?

Comment: No, Radon-Nikodym states that, if a (sigma-fin.) measure $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to a (sigma-fin.) measure $\lambda$, then there is a measurable, positive function $f$ with $\mu = f d\lambda$. If you are given a measure $\mu = f d\lambda$, e.g. $\mu(A)=\int_A f d\lambda$ for all measurable $A$, then you can prove that $\int g d\mu = \int g \cdot f d\lambda$ by algebraic induction (you have to show first, that the identity holds for indicators  $\int 1_A fd\mu = \mu(A) = \int_A f d\lambda = \int 1_A \cdot f d\lambda$, then for lin. combinations and limits).

Comment: Sorry, I am some confused. First, remember that for any borelian $B$, $P_{\small X}(B) = \int_B f(x) dx $. More precisaly, $P_{\small X}(B) = \int_B f(x) d\lambda(x)$, where $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure. Radon Nikodyn says that if $P_{\small X} << \lambda$ - that is $\lambda(B) = 0$ implies $P_{\small X}(B) = \int_B f(x) d\lambda(x) = 0$ - then there is a unique $f$ that $d P_{\small X}/d\lambda  = f$, in other words, $d P_{\small X}  = f d\lambda$. With this consequence, I can say that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} xdP_{\small{X}}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x f(x)dx$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: No, you are mixing things up. Already your first identity $P_X(B)=\int_B f(x) d\lambda(x)$ is NOT true in general. It is true if and only if  $P_X$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\lambda$, then there exists an measurable, positive $f$ with $P_X=f d\lambda$ (this is the Radon-Nikodym Theorem). For instance, for the deterministic rv $X=0$, we have that $\lambda(\{0\})=0$, but $P_X(\{0\})=1$, hence $P_X$ is  not absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\lambda$ and hence there is no such $f$. But IF you have that $P_X = f d\lambda$, than you can show , that $\int g dP_X = \int g \cdot f d\lambda(x)$.

Comment: And the way you show it is by algebraic induction: first you show that it is true for indicator functions. Than assume that it is true for two functions $g_1$ and $g_2$, show that it is true for a linear combination of the two. Then assume it is true for a (monotonic,dominated) converging sequence $f_n$, show that it is true for the limit.

Comment: Ok, In my case, the random variable $X$ is absolutely continuous, that is, $P_{X}$ is absolutely continuous. In this particular situation, I can use the 
 Radon-Nikodym. In the other situations, it is necessary arguer  by algebraic induction. Now, am I right?

Comment: No. $P_X$ is absolutely continuous. Hence Radon-Nikodym tells you that there is a positive measurable $f$ with $P_X=f d\lambda$. Now IF you have any measure of the form $\mu= f d\lambda$, than there is a theorem  how to calculate integrals: If $g$ is integrable (w.r.t. $\lambda$ or $\mu$), than $$\int g d\mu = \int g \cdot f d\lambda$$. This you can prove by algebraic induction. If your measure is not absolutely continuous than "there is no f" and of course no such identity.